# ASP.NET: Set a decimal valued Response.StatusCode

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, iis

Simple question this time, is there a way in ASP.NET to set a decimal value HTTP Status Code instead of the common int status code?

Example, I would like to set a "403.4 SSL required" instead of just a 403...

Thanks :)

---

** EDIT

The comments below pointed me in the right direction, I just needed to set the Response.SubStatusCode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the standard HTTP only defines 3 digit numeric result codes. What you are seeing is IIS specific, it is the *sub-status code* which can be set and read from the [`HttpResponse.SubStatusCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.substatuscode.aspx) property.

From MSDN:

> The SubStatusCode property is only supported with the integrated
>   pipeline mode in IIS 7.0 and at least the .NET Framework version 3.0.
>   When you set the SubStatusCode property, the status is logged on IIS
>   7.0 if failed-request tracing is configured. Independent of whether tracing is configured, the code is never sent as part of the final
>   response to the request. For more information, see Troubleshooting
>   Failed Requests Using Failed Request Tracing in IIS 7.0.

Comment: HttpResponse.SubStatusCode is not available in .Net Core 2.2.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a decimal [HTTP Status Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).

Whatever you're trying to accomplish isn't by using HTTP status codes.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403 has a full list of status codes that have a decimal value.  Is that platform specific (like only valid in IIS)?

Comment: Didn't know about that but it must be platform specific, for sure. As @Matthew said *RFC 2616 section 6.1.1 says it must be a "3-digit integer result code."*

Answer (score 0):

No.  RFC 2616 [section 6.1.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html#sec6.1.1) says it must be a "3-digit integer result code."